# Bayesian statistics, machine learning: prior v.s hyperprior

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, bayesian

I have a linear regression (say) model 
p(t|x;w) = N(t ; m , D);

Being Bayesian, I can put a Gaussian prior on parameter w.
However, I've realized for some models we can put Gaussian-Wishart hyperprior on the Gaussian to be 'more' Bayesian. Is this correct ? Are both of these two models valid Bayesian models ?

It seems to me that we can always put hyperprior, hyperhyperprior,.......... because it will still be a valid probabilistic model.

I am wondering what's the difference between putting a prior and putting the hyperprior on the prior. Are they both Bayesian ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a hyperprior is still "valid Bayesian" in the sense that this sort of hierarchical modeling is comes naturally to Bayesian models, and just about any book/course on Bayesian modeling does go through the use of hyperpriors.

It's completely fine to use Normal-Wishart as the prior (or hyperprior) of a Gaussian distribution. I guess it's, in some sense, even "more Bayesian" to do so if doing so models the phenomenon at hand more accurately.

I'm not sure what you mean by "are they both Bayesian" when it comes to the difference between using a prior and a hyperprior. Bayesian hierarchical models with hyperpriors are still Bayesian models.

Comment: My question comes from Bayesian linear regression and (say) bayesian mixture of Gaussians. Bayesian linear regression does not put hyperprior over its gasussian prior. However, Bayesian mixture of Gaussians do so. At the first sight I can not tell why doesn't Bayesian linear regression does not put hyperprior on the top. So I am not sure what's the difference (and it's not mentioned in the book, at least in mine book lol). Is the difference only whether being hierarchical or not ?

Comment: I'm not an expert of Bayesian linear regression, but from a quick look it looks to be using a prior with linear regression, which should mean using a hyperprior is also ok. It just means you have several Bayesian linear regression models with parameters coming from the hyperprior distribution, which I guess is a rare enough case not to be covered explicitly in the book.

Answer (score 3):

Using hyperpriors only makes sense in a hierarchical Bayesian model. In that case you would be looking at multiple groups and estimate a group specific coefficient w_group based on group specific priors, with coefficients drawn from a global hyperprior.

If your prior and hyperprior reside on the same hierarchical level, which seems to be the case you are think about, then the effect on the results is the same as using a simple prior with a wider standard deviation. Since it still requires additional computational costs, such stacking should be avoided.

There is a lot of statistical literature on how to pick non-informative priors, often theoretically best solutions are improper distributions (their total integral is infinite) and there is a large risk of getting improper posterior solutions without well defined means or even medians. So for practical purposes picking wide normal distributions usually works best.